# files comparison in linux using line numbers

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am looking to compare file1.txt contents  with the last n file contents of file2.txt Can someone help in identifying this logic using anything in shell script.
Example if file1.txt has 10 lines, the last 10 lines of file2.txt should be compared for difference.

Comment: So would the algorithm be, "count lines in file1, extract that many lines from the end of file2, then diff"?  You can count lines in file1 using `wc -l`, and extract lines from the end of file2 using `tail`.

Comment: Post sample input, expected output, and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

With bash's [process substitution](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC35) `<()` and [command substitution](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC33) `$()`.

```
diff file1.txt <(tail -n $(wc -l < file1.txt) file2.txt)
```